# trying to debug electron app, and window not showing up

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

I am attempting to debug an electron app in vs code (the main process, not the renderer process). The project I am trying to debug is this repo:

```
https://github.com/hello-efficiency-inc/raven-reader
```

it works really nice, once you have it cloned, and the right things are installed. Then I can just run:

```
yarn electron:serve
```

And boom, it runs nicely.
But I would like to also debug this. So I look around a bit, and find that I should probably use this launch.json file in the .vscode directory:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Electron: Main",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--remote-debugging-port=9223", "."],
      "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In my package.json, I have this line for finding the startfile:

```
"main": "./src/background.js",
```

So, I try to run by clicking the debug icon, and then green triangle where it says

```
run and debug | Electron:Main
```

Which gives me this in the call stack menu:

[image]

But nothing actually seems like it's running, I dont see any desktop window which I would like so I can actually debug, and I can't hit my breakpoints either

Comment: what happens when you set a breakpoint. Is it active? Might something be crashing at the top-level?

Answer (score -1):

Best way to sort this is to install code runner extension in vscode